# How to make bouncycastle .net libraries talk to FIPS validated .net implementation

Tags: .net, x509certificate, bouncycastle, fips

We are currently building a certificate authority .net that will:

1. Generate a root certificate
2. Use the root certificate to issue device certs.
3. Revoke a device certificate
4. Generate a Certificate Revocation List.
5. Generate a Delta CRL

We are currently using BouncyCastle .net libraries to achieve this. The second phase of the project is to make the above mentioned functionality fips validated. We understand that bouncy castle libraries are not fips validated. We are using FIPS validated Microsoft libraries elsewhere in our product.

Is there any way to make Bouncy castle communicate with the FIPS validated Microsoft libraries?